# Generate Local Resource for all pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resources, auto-generate

Is There Any Way or trick to generate local resource for all pages in visual studio 2010 automatically?
I have about 500 pages and UserControls. its hard to generate resource for every page one by one.
is there Any Add on or extension for this?
shaahin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a script, no? A resource file is nothing but an XML file.

Comment: yes its just an XML file.
how can i write script or extension or add in for doing that?
give me clues please.
how can i doing that?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Write a macro as suggested in [Is it possoble to run 'Generate Local Resources Tool' programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769938/is-it-possoble-to-run-generate-local-resources-tool-programmatically)

Also from http://www.guysmithferrier.com/post/2009/05/Localizing-ASPNET-MVC.aspx :

Convert your HTML controls to equivalent ASP.NET server side controls. If this is your plan then you should take a look at the I18NRefactorings (an add-in for the free DXCore) in the download at http://www.dotneti18n.com/Downloads.aspx (folder VS2010/ASPNETSpecifics/I18NRefactorings/I18NRefactorings in the 2010 zip) that will help automate this process.